# How to convert a folder of images to h5 file?

Tags: python, hdf5

How do you convert a folder of images into h5 file? or is there a different type of file format for inputting the dataset to the CNN model?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could store each file (i.e. image) as an HDF5 dataset of datatype `opaque`. Additionally, for each dataset you could associate one or more attributes to describe the file (e.g. creation timestamp).

Using [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) in Python, this could be implemented as follows:

```
import HDFql

HDFql.execute("CREATE AND USE FILE images.h5") # create HDF5 file named 'images.h5' and use (i.e. open) it

HDFql.execute("SHOW FILE my_directory/") # get files (i.e. images) stored in directory 'my_directory' and populate cursor with result

i = 1
while HDFql.cursor_next() == HDFql.SUCCESS: # loop through cursor

   file_name = HDFql.cursor_get_char()

   dataset_name = "dataset_%04d" % i

   HDFql.execute("CREATE DATASET %s VALUES FROM BINARY FILE \"%s\"" % (dataset_name, file_name)) # create HDF5 dataset and write data from file into it

   i = i + 1
```